# Using default URL value in Django throws 404 error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to use a default value for url in my views, however, I keep getting a 404 error.

I have set the default value both in my view and in my url path settings:

This is my url:

```
path('u/<str:username>/<obj>/', views.get_user, kwargs={'obj':None}, name="get_user"),
```

This is my view:

```
def get_user(request, username, obj=None):

How can I set the default value of `obj` to none so I can for instance visit `u/jack/posts/` and `u/jack/` using the same URL pattern
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make two urls, one without the URL parameter and a default, and one *with* an `<obj>`:

```
path('u/<str:username>/', views.get_user, kwargs={'obj':None}, name='get_user'),
path('u/<str:username>/<obj>/', views.get_user, name='get_user'),
```